# Install 20.04 LTS from WSL2 ubuntu backup

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Basically I no longer want to use Win10 and want to switch to Ubuntu completely. I have a WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 with lots of packages. Is there a easy way to migrate/fresh install Ubuntu through the ubuntu `.bak` file of WSL2?

Comment: There is no such way. You'll need a fresh install.

Comment: @Pilot6 thanks. How do I migrate from wsl2 to the new ubuntu system after the fresh install? Can I use something like clonezilla or is there a better way?

Comment: You can't "migrate", you can install same packages, etc.